# How do I add the values from three arrays?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there an easy way to add the elements of arrays together?  Let's say I have 3 arrays.

```
[15,22,35,40]
[10,20,12,20]
[11,24,14,22]
```

What I want to do is add up the totals so it would be:

```
[36,66,61,82]
```

and then overwrite [11,24,14,22] with those values.

Forgot to add the code I already have:

```
function combineItems(){
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j] == "Product A") {
        medData = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7, 1, 4).getValues();
        console.log(medData);
      }
      if (values[i][j] == "Product B") {
        smData = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7, 1, 4).getValues();
        console.log(smData);
      }
      if (values[i][j] == "Product C") {
        newData = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7, 1, 4).getValues();
        console.log(newData);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I want to add up Product A, Product B, and Product C and then overwrite Product C with those new totals.

Comment: Show what you've tried with a [mcve]

Comment: @TheMaster knew I forgot something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
function myFunction(data) {

  return data[data.length-1].map((i, index) => i = 
           data.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr[index], 0)
         )

}
```

**Example:**

```
const productA = [15,22,35,40]
const productB = [10,20,12,20]
const productC = [11,24,14,22] 

const newData = myFunction([productA, productB, productC])

/** 

Expected Output:

  [36.0, 66.0, 61.0, 82.0]

**/
```

**How It Works:**

Taking the input of a multidimensional array, we alter the last row in place (`.map()`) by reducing (`.reduce()`) all values of the input data by index for each row.
*(Reduce each column of the data into the last row.)*

Suggested Reading:

- [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I appreciate the attempt but I am looking to sum them, not append to one array.

Comment: Easy fix, updated.

Comment: It does not.  The output from Product A, Product B and Product C are:

8:50:14 AM Info [ [ 0, 3390, 0, 0 ] ]
8:50:14 AM Info [ [ 1033.5, 0, 1500, 150 ] ]
8:50:14 AM Info [ [ 100, 1609, 0, 0 ] ]

I want it to read like this:

[1133.5, 4999, 1500, 150]

I am getting this:
[ '00,3390,0,0100,1609,0,01033.5,0,1500,150' ]

Comment: It looks like you're inputting nested arrays ( [[]] ), when you should be inputting arrays ([]). Try adding `.flat()` at the end of wherever you're retrieving these values.